# PBS commands return wrong output or not output at all

Tags: bash, unix, cluster-computing, pbs

I have run the following lines from the terminal, one by one:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -lnodes=1:ppn=8
#PBS -lwalltime=48:00:00
echo $PBS_O_WORKDIR
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
cat $PBS_NODEFILE
```

Line `echo $PBS_O_WORKDIR` returns an empty line.
`cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR` returns the home directory instead of the directory I was launching the command from.
Line `cat $PBS_NODEFILE` is simple hanging, without doing anything.
This used always to work, do you have any idea about what's going on?

An additional note. When trying to submit the following script with `qsub`, it simply hangs, alternating between status R and Q.

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N test
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=1
echo “Hi”
date
echo “############################”
env
echo “############################”
echo “bye”
exit 0
```

Comment: assuming the `PBS` commands (aliases? functions?) populate the `$PBS*` variables ... all of the `PBS` commands are commented out so none of the `$PBS*` variables are going to get set, hence all of the follow-on commands (`echo`, `cd`, and `cat`) are behaving just like they normally would when provided no arguments

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `PBS` is, but it sounds like the environment variables aren't set.

So, on that assuption

- When you `echo` with no arguments, it will simply output an empty line.
- When you `cd` with no arguments, it defaults to `$HOME`
- When you `cat` with no arguments, it waits for information on stdin (which will create the illusion that it hangs, as ti will keep on waiting forever)

So, the question becomes: when is those variables supposed to be set?

So, until `env | awk -F= '$1 ~ /^PBS_O_(WORKDIR|NODEFILE)$/'` outputs anything, the commands don't have an argument to pass and the result you experience is expected.